# I am trying to match a string with particular word, but i am getting an error cannot read property input of null in else

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After executing this, only else is giving output. But if there are no similar words, then if is not logging the statement, it's giving an error `cannot read property 'input' of null`, what should I do.

I want to match particular words, so i am using `match.input` method to give me only string.

```js
function checkTargetInputValues() {
  if (matchWords.input !== titleInput) {
    console.log("Add SEO keyowrds in your title");
  } else {
    console.log("congrats you are using seo keywords");
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to print the matchWords before the if statement and see what you got, generally I would suggest you to use debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below in order to avoid the crashing of application. As per your implementation I'm assuming `matchWords` is an object and hence made changes accordingly.

```js
function checkTargetInputValues() {
  if ((matchWords || {}).input !== titleInput) {
    console.log("Add SEO keyowrds in your title");
  } else {
    console.log("congrats you are using seo keywords");
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.